# Divide by count result using PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, count, divide

I am trying to divide by the number of rows in my table, at the minute I am entering the value to be divide by manually using:

```
<?php
$result10 = $result10 * 100 / 10 (<-- Result from count)
?>
```

I presume I need to count the rows and replace 10 with the $query_result but I have tried this and am not sure exactly what to do and if it is possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You realize you can do this *in* the query?

Comment: I know how to count the rows in the table but am unsure how to divide by the result?

Comment: Consider the PHP `count()` function if you won't use it in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

As an example of how to do this in the query:

```
select result10 / (select count(*) from <yourquery>)
from <your query>
```

If you are doing a simple average, then this might be the most appropriate solution:

```
select avg(colx)
from t
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could do it

```
 <?php
define('HOST','hostdetails');
define('USER','userdetails');
define('PASS','passdetails');
define('DB','dbdetails');

$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$rowcount = $stmt->num_rows;
//$result10 -> add your variable for result10 here, however you are generating it...

$result10 = (($result10*100)/$rowcount);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$result10 = $result10 * 100 / $num_rows (<-- Result from count)
```